# Auto-Indent between HTML tags in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, auto-indent

Typing `<html>` automatically creates `</html>` after your cursor in Notepad++:
[Staring Point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NplNE.png)

But when you press <kbd>enter</kbd>, it just puts the closing tag on the next line:
[This is what it does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQM6m.png)

How can I do this automatically so that pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> results in:
[This is what I want it to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixp1V.png)

Couldn't find a setting or plugin which does this.

This kind of feature works for `{}` for programming languages like C, C++, Java, even for CSS but not for HTML. Something like this...
[Feature for C++ lang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFnoi.gif)